# NSURLConnection didSendBodyData progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, uiprogressview, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I'm using a POST request to upload some data to a server, and I'm trying to update the UIProgressView's progress based on the `totalBytesWritten` property of the `didSendBodyData` method of `NSURLConnection`. Using the below code, I don't get a proper updating of the progress view, it's always 0.000 until it finishes. I'm not sure what to multiply or divide by to get a better progress of the upload.

I'd appreciate any help offered! Code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    NSNumber *progress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite)];

    NSLog(@"Proggy: %f",progress.floatValue);

    self.uploadProgressView.progress = progress.floatValue;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to cast the bytesWritten and the bytesExpected as `float` values to divide.

```
float myProgress = (float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
progressView.progress = myProgress;
```

Otherwise you are will get either a 0 or some other number as a result of dividing 2 integers.

ie: `10 / 25 = 0`

`10.0 / 25.0 = 0.40`

Objective-C provides the `modulus` operator `%` for determining remainder and is useful for dividing integers.

Answer (score 2):

You code looks good. Try to use a big file like 20 MB to 50 MB for upload.

If you use a UIProgressView you can set the progress in the connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: method like this:

```
 float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
 float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];
 progressView.progress = progress/total;
```

In simple code:

```
progressView.progress = (float)totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

Hope it will help you.